# Migration of NIS yppasswd hashes from crypt to md5

Tags: linux, migration, md5, passwd, nis

Imagine a NIS user database `/var/yp/input-files/passwd` consisting of old crypt DES hashes. The aim is to migrate this database to md5 or sha hashes. When changing a password using `yppasswd`, it is generated using the same algorithm as for the existing entry (probably for legacy reasons), i.e. *crypt stays crypt, md5 stays md5*.

Our current plan is to write a special password change script wrapping yppasswd. Is there a more elegant way to tell yppasswd to generate changed passwords in md5 format by default?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by now:

1. Download the nis-package of your distribution e.g. `apt-get source nis` under Debian.
2. Edit corresponding yp-tools-2.9/src/yppasswd.c
3. Replace `int has_md5_passwd = 0;` by `int has_md5_passwd = 1;` in the beginning of `int main (int argc, char **argv)`

yppasswd then always creates md5 hashes.

Comment: This doesn't exactly work with the yppasswd in yp-tools 2.12.  If you go this route, you'll need to set `int hash_id = MD5;` at the top of `main` _and_ comment out the later line that says `hash_id = get_hash_id (pwd->pw_passwd);`.

Answer (score 1):

Recent Linux distributions support NIS password updates through PAM, which means you can use the local `passwd` program instead of `yppasswd`.  This also means that you can configure the hash algorithm, which is still (as of yp-tools 2.12) not possible with `yppasswd`.

Your system should have an `/etc/pam.d/passwd` file, which will either contain or, more likely, refer to another file that contains a line of the form:

```
password  sufficient  pam_unix.so md5 nis
```

The second field might differ, and there might be other parameters at the end, but you want the `password` line that loads `pam_unix.so` and it should have at least the `nis` parameter as well as a hash function appropriate to your NIS server (`md5`, `sha256`, etc.)

Your distribution might have a better way of configuring this, though, so make sure your changes aren't going to be overwritten by an automated process later.

On RedHat-derived systems (including at least RHEL, CentOS, Scientific Linux, and Fedora), you need to use the `authconfig` program with at least the `--enablenis` parameter.  For the above scenario with MD5 hashes, the following command line would be sufficient:

```
authconfig --enablenis --usemd5 --update
```

On Debian systems (and possibly Debian derivatives, but I can't check at the moment), the proper way to do this appears to be to copy `/usr/share/pam-configs/unix` to something else (say, `/usr/share/pam-configs/nis`), edit the new file to give it appropriate settings and a new profile name, then run `pam-auth-update`, disable the "Unix authentication" profile and enable your new profile.